# Attributing a number to each word in a column in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In my Google Sheet, I have a column consisting in a list of words that can be duplicates:

```
love
love
work
physics
space
work
mechanics
```

And I need for each unique word to have its own identifying number, such as this:

```
love      | 1
love      | 1
work      | 2
physics   | 3
space     | 4
work      | 2
mechanics | 5
```

To achieve this, I guess I could first remove the duplicates and just drag the numbers down til the last word, like this:

```
love      | 1
work      | 2
physics   | 3
space     | 4
mechanics | 5
```

But then, how would I go on about attributing the right number to each word of the original column?

Comment: What formula have you tried?

Comment: @Jescanellas Ideally I was hoping to be able to do something like this: `=SUBSTITUTE(B1:B, E1, F1)`, columns E and F being the last table I put in my post, but unfortunately formulas don't work that way (and SUBSTITUTE only analyses one cell at a time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `MATCH` for every cell in a column against a `UNIQUE` for the same column:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(MATCH(A:A, UNIQUE(A:A), 0)))
```

[image]

It will give a row number for that word in a column with duplicates removed.

Or just use `MATCH` against the column itself if you need distinct numbers and do not mind that some will be skipped:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(MATCH(A:A, A:A, 0)))
```

[image]

This way you'll get a row number for the first occurrence of a word in the original column.